# How to use a [WebMethod] in server script blocks in the aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, webmethod

I'm trying to create a simple .Net 3.5 page thas has some HTML and a `WebMethod`. When I try to call my `WebMethod` from my browser, but it keeps returing the page. Any ideas how to get it to work?

This is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="CFW.WebUI.Page" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Test()
    {
        return "Hola!";
    }

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
</html>
```

Note: I'm *not* using Ajax.Net. I just want to call the WebMethod from the client (using jQuery).

Comment: consider using services like asmx

Comment: I would like to keep it together in one file. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course, once you defined them all in one file.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use .Net webforms and webservices in one ASMX file.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SayHello()
{
     return "Hola";
}
```

In your page you need to add a `ScriptManager` and set the `EnablePageMethods` property to `true` as so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="sMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />
```

All that does is that it creates a `Javascript` proxy class on your page that will allow you to call you `SayHello` method by just doing the following in Javascript:

```
function InvokeSayHello()
{
     alert(PageMethods.SayHello()); //Will alert 'Hola'
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it without the use of Ajax.Net.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
```

use

```
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works without the `ScriptManager`, but it is definately possible to call a `PageMethod` without using the `PageMethod` keyword. You can call your ASP page just like any other webservice, eg. `yourpage.aspx/MethodName`. The function should be decorated with a `[WebMethod]` attribute, there is no need to put the `[ScriptMethod]` tag or anything on the page class itself. I do notice I `POST` data to these functions rather than `GET`, but I am not sure if this is required.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]  to your method as well :

**

http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx

Comment: Added it... `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` doesn't fix it. But it is good to have it there :-).