# Bind datatable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

I am trying to populate a datatable with data from SQL database. I have the following C# code which does return the correct number of records.

```
       public class myClass
        {
            public int CenterID { get; set; }
            public string CenterName { get; set; }
            public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
            public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
            public string YearID { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static List<myClass> Bind()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
        WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        List<myClass> newClass = new List<myClass>();
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("zCenterDetails_get", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            newClass.Add(new myClass
            {
                CenterID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CenterID"]),
                CenterName = rdr["CenterName"].ToString(),
                LicenseKey = rdr["LicenseKey"].ToString(),
                ExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ExpiryDate"]),
                YearID = rdr["YearID"].ToString(),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Date"]),
            });
        }
        con.Close();
        return newClass;
    }
```

The thing that I am struggling with is binding the data with AJAX. This is what I've tried so far but I know it is not correct. Please assist me to get my data into the datatable as I am new to datatables. Thanks

This is what I have so far:

```
function Bind() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/Bind",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#datatable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'CenterID' },
                    { 'data': 'CenterName' },
                    { 'data': 'LicenseKey' },
                    { 'data': 'ExpiryDate' },
                    { 'data': 'YearID' },
                    { 'data': 'Date' }
                ]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650969/how-to-use-a-webmethod-in-server-script-blocks-in-the-aspx-page

Comment: I believe I have everything that is said in the link you sent. I am struggling with the ajax part.

Comment: what happens when you type the ajax URL in the browser...do you get the content back?